# how to access a function without the parameter?

Tags: c++

see i have a file with a function "add" like below

```
 #pragma once;

 class fun {

     boolean s_function(){
         if(s.size() > 2) {
             return true;
         }
         return false;
     }
 };
```

then i have another file

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    fun x;
    string s = "wtf";

    cout << x.s.s_function() << endl;
}
```

i can see obviously `x.s.s_function()` is so weird and won't work. so how to actually call such function with no parameter properly in the second file?

Comment: Have you tried `x.s_function()`?

Comment: Your file that contains the `fun` class won't compile.  Fix that first and proceed from there.

Comment: yes I did, its not working

Comment: What is x.s? What is "boolean"? Why are you trying to call a private method from outside the class?

Comment: You could make `s` global (very bad) or make `s` a static member of `fun`. Why can it not have a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

s_function is a member of the class fun, so the correct way to do this would be:

```
bool s_function(std::string s)
{
}
```

and then call it as:

```
x.s_function(s);
```

which will return a bool that you can work with

Otherwise, the first file has no idea that the string s exists in the second file, which is because s has a local scope (which means it gets created when main is called and deleted when main ends, but doesn't exist outside of that time period).

Passing it to s_function will create a copy for s_function to work with. However, s_function wont actually be able to modify the string s declared in main() because it actually has a copy. (In order to change the one in main, it would need to be passed by reference.)

Hope that helps.

Comment: yea, thats make sense. what if i declare fun class like fun *x; then call the function using pointer like  x->function(s); but what i want is without change the s_function, thats the problem that i want to solve

Comment: Careful. If you declare a class `fun *x`, you'll actually be creating a pointer to a class. But if x did point to something (if you initialized it), then you could call `x->s_function();` However, without changing s_function, the only option for manipulating the string is by having it in [scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope)